# iPhone XS Max - went into disabled mode

Tags: data-recovery, iphone, ios, file-recovery

I accidentally dropped my iPhone and part of the screen wasn't functioning. So I entered the incorrect passcode several times (Maybe around 10) and the phone got disabled.

Now, I have replaced the screen but my data is lost. I have some very sentimental pictures taken from this phone which is not backed. How can I recover these pictures ?

I used Dr.Fone and PhoneRescue, it recovered almost all the pictures except for the ones taken on the day I dropped the phone. I am not able to recover these images. Can someone please help me out?

Comment: You might want to try [iExplorer](https://macroplant.com/iexplorer). I've used it to recover plenty of data for iPhones & iPads. _Disclaimer: Satisfied user of iExplorer. No financial or other ties to Macroplant LLC._

Comment: After/If you get your photos back, be sure to back them up!

Comment: @IconDaemon When I contacted the company OnTrack they said that it is impossible to recover lost data from iPhone 6s Onwards. What are your thoughts on it ?

Comment: @fsb Yes Sir. Next time.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using iMazing, as I've found that it has worked in multiple similar situations (water damage, dead screen, etc.

I'm afraid that iMazing is a paid app, but comes with a 30 day trial, but in my experience this trial can be reset  by uninstalling and reinstalling iMazing.