# Will repeating Updating in disable mode results in disable updating in DFU mode?

Tags: iphone, ios, apple-id

**Edited**:

My iPhone 7 was disabled and it asked to connect to iTunes because of trying more than 10 times passcode.(don't have backup/iClould enabled)

Then i remembered my correct passcode.

I tried to update (DFU) the disabled iPhone(14.4 to 14.6) to find (one more time) chance to try correct passcode,because i thought i can recover data of my disabled iPhone with updating.(not restoring)

After updating phone in DFU mode, iPhone asked me passcode, after that,Recovery data process started ,but at the end of recovery process failed , and said "data recovery failed".Update was not done completely each time.

I tried updating again some more times (3-4 times).The same result > "data recovery failed" each time.

But After that , phone didn't ask me passcode anymore.like prev times and didn't try to recover my data at all.**

Before trying for next time this happened(Accidental) :

I have changed my apple ID password because i was trying to login apple site for first time and apple locked my new login because of security issue after that i unlocked my apple ID account ,but forced me to change apple ID password,after that (I'm not sure if really it's related or not),iPhone 7 the phone (with the same apple ID) that I'm trying to update says "Phone is disabled" and after updating it doesn't ask me passcode anymore, like prev times and doesn't try to recover my data at all.
Maybe it's not related to changing apple ID password and not recovering data is because of repeating update process.

**Question**  : Did this(not asking passcode and not going in data recovery step) happen because of phone that is in DFU mode doesn't have new apple ID process ? Does updating in DFU mode authenticate apple ID  ?
OR
it's(not asking passcode and not going in data recovery step) because of trying updating phone for 4-5 times ?

Regards

Comment: This is still very confused. The phone's passcode & the Apple ID & password are unrelated. The passcode is specific to that one device. The Apple ID & associated password are applicable to all devices you own using the same ID.

Comment: This site works better with one question per, well, question, you can always ask separate questions. I see that you posted several questions already, but please make them focus on one problem only.

Comment: @nohillside Thanks I've edited post just now, and only asked main question.

Comment: I'f you'd had a backup, this would be easy. As you don't, you'll probably have to pick one of the myriad "iPhone rescue" apps & pay to see if it might work.

Comment: @Tetsujin Thanks, As soon as a device says it is disabled the data are lost because disabling delete the key used to decrypt the data. The data are still on the device but not readable by anybody.
Now question is : I have updated although after update process, data recovery failed, now are data still on device or erased ?? if data is erased does any rescue app can recover and decrypt data?do you know one?

Comment: It's not a situation I've ever been in. I am scrupulous about always having backups.

Comment: @Tetsujin Thanks , so you mean "iPhone rescue" is for the time that data isn't erased ? or may it help for times that data is erased ?

Comment: I don't know. It's not a situation I've ever been in. I've never had to test whether these apps are actually any good or not. You're probably going to have to buy at least one before you'll find out for sure.

Comment: I'm confused someone had the same problem like me and could recover data of disabled phone with drfone and phone rescue https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/380951/iphone-xs-max-went-into-disabled-mode   .......and others say : As soon as a device says it is disabled the data are lost because disabling delete the key used to decrypt the data. The data are still on the device but not readable by anybody  ....so how that person has recovered his data without backup and disabled phone??

Comment: Your latest edit completely changed the focus of the question. We prefer questions to stay focused on their original topic, you can always ask a new question if necessary.

Answer (score 1):

If you change the Apple ID password and one device has the correct password and the other device does not have the correct password then the device without the correct password will fail to authenticate until you change the saved password on that device.

Updating an Apple device in recovery DFU mode is typically performed via Apple Configurator 2 or perhaps iTunes on Windows.  You do not need to authenticate to Apple to load iOS / iPadOS / macOS via Apple Configurator.  You will need to authenticate on the device itself.  If you are using an MDM or Configuration Profiles on Apple Configurator you can configure the device to login to a particular Apple ID.

UPDATED After question edited:

**Always backup your iPhone**. iCloud backup is the easiest no brainer way to backup.  If you don't have enough storage you can upgrade iCloud storage to 50GB's by paying $1/mo. or $3/mo. for 200GB or $10/mo for 2TB of storage. Storage plans of 200GB+ are eligible for family sharing. ***An iCloud backup may be deleted after 180 days if it's not updated by the device that created it.***

Alternative to iCloud backup is to backup to a PC with iTunes or a Mac. A backup to a computer is a complete backup while an iCloud backup is only your data and settings. But you do need to remember to actually backup the iPhone with this method where iCloud is completely automatic once you turn the feature on.

If you had either an iCloud or full backup made on a computer, you would have been able to wipe out the iPhone entirely and restore from iCloud during the activation process (after logging on with the correct Apple ID password). Or after imaging the iPhone during DFU and backup restoration you would be prompted for the Apple ID and password.

If Erase Data is turned on under Settings -> Passcode (TouchID / FaceID) then it will self-erase after 10 failed password attempts to unlock the iPhone.  It will pause after a few attempts and disable the iPhone to prevent you from continuously attempting to guess the password.  The timeout increases exponentially every time you continue to fail to unlock the iPhone.  At the 10th and final failure it would have taken over and hour to get to that point. If the 10th time you fail it will factory reset itself.

During initial operating system activation it will prompt for the Apple ID & Password.  This is called Activation Lock. It is an anti-theft feature. If you don't know your password you can reset the password via https://appleid.apple.com and after a few minutes it should work providing the iPhone was connected to Wi-Fi or cellular data.

In order to clear the Activation Lock the owner needs to remove the device from the iCloud account via icloud.com. This will clear the prompt for the Activation lock within a few minutes providing the iPhone is online via Wi-Fi / Cellular.

If you fully lockout your Apple ID then you need to call Apple Support to get it unlocked.

In the upcoming iOS 15 there is a feature to add a friend or relative to help validate your identity if you are locked out of your Apple ID.  A code will be sent to your friend or family member who can then give you the code verbally and then using that code you will be able to unlock your account.  This was added because in some instances recovery was not possible and users had to create a new Apple ID.  Another feature was added where you can designate a beneficiary of sorts who upon your death will be granted access to your Apple account. I believe you must provide an official death certificate but the designee would then be able to access the device.

What should your next steps be?

**BACKUP YOUR IPHONE**
Either to iCloud or via USB Lightning cable to PC with iTunes or a Mac and performing a full backup.

First try going to Settings -> General -> Reset -> Erase all Settings and Content.  When the iPhone reboots see if you can update to the latest iOS version.  If this again fails you will require a PC or Mac so you can put the iPhone in DFU mode and reload iOS from scratch over the USB lightning cable.  At that point, it should be the latest iOS version.  During device activation, restore from iCloud.  Restoring from the full backup on PC / Mac would likely result it being restored back to the older iOS version.  So iCloud is really necessary to fix your particular scenario. Otherwise you may restore the problem.  If you don't use iCloud much the 5GB of free storage might be just enough to hold one backup (if you are lucky). If not then you must purchase additional storage.  The 50GB storage plan is plenty.

Comment: So you mean the Update process (DFU mode) doesn't check if apple ID password is correct or not? I described whole story below Please check it ,Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, As soon as a device says it is disabled the data are lost because disabling delete the key used to decrypt the data. The data are still on the device but not readable by anybody.
Now question is : I have updated although after update process, data recovery failed, now are data still on device or erased ?? if data is erased does any rescue app can recover and decrypt data?do you know one?

Comment: @alabd Once the key is lost/deleted, it doesn't really matter whether the data is still there or not. It's encrypted, and without the key you won't be able to recover it.